# trans function in side lists function of laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get data from database by using lists('keys','values') that I have to display in blade template form helper and I want translate values in different languages using laravel's trans () method. Is there any way to use tran() method in side lists method. Here is my code...

mycontroller.php

```
public function step2($id) {
        $model = Questionair::find($id);
        $Activity = Activity::lists('kcal.name','value');
        $user = $this->currentUser;
        if (isset($_POST['any_physical_activity'])) {
            $data = Input::all();
            $model->fill($data);
            $model->save();
            return redirect('questionair/step3/' . $model->id);
        }
        return view('myview.blade.php', compact('model', 'model', 'user', 'users','Activity','Activity'));
    }
```

myview.blade.php

```
{!!Form::select('any_physical_activity',$Activity,null,['class' => 'form-control hide'])!!}
```

Comment: I want to translate names that are in kcal.php file in view/lang/en

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code this works well
Here is code

```
myController.php

$Activity = Activity::lists('name', 'value');
        array_walk($Activity, function(&$item2, $key) {
            $item2 = trans('kcal.' . $item2);

        });
```